# Column header repeat don´t work in ssrs 2008

Tags: header, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with a tablix that has row headers. I want to repeat the headers on each page, so I activated the flag "Repeat header columns on each page". But nothing happens... this worked with earlier versions of ssrs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set KeepWithGroup to "After" in that Report Group properties. Need to switch to Advanced mode to see this option. How to switch to Advanced mode: click littel downward triangle on the right from "Column Groups" heading